# iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0 in Xcode 10

Tags: ios

My Xcode version is 10.2. When I upload the app to iTunes Connect, it shows the following error:

> Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0.

My resource like below:

[image]

I have added image in my info.plist like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to tick the iPad option in the Attributes inspector and then assign the 152x152 pixel icon to the iPad App slot.

[image: iPad App icon slot]